# Parsing raw PDF data to create PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I'm accessing an API to download/view a PDF of a purchase order.

The API is returning what appears to be raw PDF data, starting:

```
%PDF-1.2
%����
4 0 obj
<<
/E 12282
/H [1239 144]
/L 12655
/Linearized 1
/N 1
/O 7
/T 12527
```

I'm struggling to find a way to convert this to a downloadable PDF or to render the PDF in the browser.

I'm using PHP, i've tried echoing the response, this just displays the raw PDF in full - as you'd expect.

I've also tried defining headers before the echo:

```
 header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=purchase.pdf");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

this does generate a download, but when you open it, i get a "failed to load pdf document" error.

I've searched for a way to do this, but can't find anything close to the problem i'm having. Do i need to parse this response with something like TCPDF or am I missing something really obvious?

UPDATE:

using the code below, i can save the file to the server, if I download this, it opens and is as I'd expect, but I still can't serve it in the browser.

```
$data = $results->body;
$destination = '../pos/'.$id.'.pdf';
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
$filename = $id.'.pdf';
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($destination);
```

Comment: Can you you provide PHP code which saves binary stream to drive? It looks like corrupted binary PDF stream. E.g. make sure you have no whitespace at the end of the stream when saving (dont put closing PHP tag into PHP script and use `file_put_content`). Try adding `exit()` after `readfile($destination)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be missing some headers or have whitespace after reading stream. This works for me:

```
$path = '/file/absolute/path.pdf';
$content = '%PDF-1.4%âãÏÓ8 0 obj<< /Type ....';

// save PDF buffer
file_put_contents($path, $content);

// ensure we don't have any previous output
if(headers_sent()){
    exit("PDF stream will be corrupted - there is already output from previous code.");
}

header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');

// force download dialog
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
header('Content-Type: application/download', false);

// use the Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);

// send binary stream directly into buffer rather than into memory
readfile($path);

// make sure stream ended
exit();
```

Comment: This got me on the right path - the issue was indeed extra content, but before not after. Turns out my layout files were including a header html block and that was the cause.

Comment: @Andy I have updated script to check also output before sending PDF stream down, thanx.

Comment: How can I download pdf file in angular using above pdf string